# Nlog Write logs in files by conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, nlog, nlog.config

I have the following targets in my Nlog config file

```
<targets>
<target name ="loggerCreatePortal" xsi:type="File" 
        fileName="c:/CRM Trace Logs/Portal2.0/${shortdate}_createPortalRegForm.log"
        layout="${logger} | ${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${message}"
        createDirs="true"/>

<target name ="loggerCreateRegData" xsi:type="File"
        fileName="c:/CRM Trace Logs/Portal2.0/${shortdate}_createPortalRegFormData.log"
        layout="${logger} | ${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${message}"
        createDirs="true"/>

</targets>

<rules>

<logger name="loggerCreatePortal" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="createPortalRegForm"/>
<logger name="loggerCreateRegData" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="createPortalRegFormData"/>

</rules>
```

In my Main class:

```
public class PortalController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly Logger loggerCreatePortal = LogManager.GetLogger("loggerCreatePortal");
    private static readonly Logger loggerCreateRegData = LogManager.GetLogger("loggerCreateRegData");

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("createPortalRegForm")]
    public Response createPortalRegForm([FromBody] ExpressPoll expressPoll)
    {
        loggerCreatePortal.Info("Test 1");
        IOrganizationService _orgService = CrmConnect.GetConnection();
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("createPortalRegFormData")]
    public Response createPortalRegFormData([FromBody] FilledExpressPoll filledExpressPoll)
    {
        loggerCreateRegData.Info("Test 2");
        IOrganizationService _orgService = CrmConnect.GetConnection();
        ...
    }
```

I want to write the logs from CrmConnect class to the log file that is used for specified logger. If an app calls route CreatePortalRegForm the logs from CrmConnect class sholud be write only in file for target loggerCreatePortal.

My CrmConnect class

```
public static class CrmConnect
{
    private static readonly Logger loggerConn = LogManager.GetLogger("loggerConn");

    public static IOrganizationService GetConnection()
    {
       ....;
       if (conn.IsReady)
       loggerConn.Info("Conn successfull");
       ....
    }
```

What target i need to add or rules to my config file?

Comment: Your logger is called `"loggerConn"` and none of your logger-rules is matching that logger-name. Have you tried to fix the logger-rules in your NLog.config ?

Comment: @RolfKristensen hi, at the moment i have not config rule for "loggerCon". And my question is whats rule i need to write to get what i want

Comment: Created an answer where I have added `CrmConnect` to the list of logger-rules.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a `rule` for your target, specyfing the class from which you want to capture logs, and which log level:

```
    <targets>
        <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="My.NameSpace.ClassName" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />
    </rules>
```

in this example the target `logfile` will only get the logs from `ClassName` from `My.Namespace` Namespace

Comment: Hi Kebek i forgot to write my rules. Of course i have it in my config file. I've edited my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are pointing to non-existing target-names:

```
<rules>
   <logger name="loggerCreatePortal" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="createPortalRegForm"/>
   <logger name="loggerCreateRegData" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="createPortalRegFormData"/>
</rules>
```

This might work:

```
<targets>
   <target name="createPortalRegForm" xsi:type="File" 
        fileName="c:/CRM Trace Logs/Portal2.0/${shortdate}_createPortalRegForm.log"
        layout="${logger} | ${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${message}"
        createDirs="true"/>
   <target name="createPortalRegFormData" xsi:type="File"
        fileName="c:/CRM Trace Logs/Portal2.0/${shortdate}_createPortalRegFormData.log"
        layout="${logger} | ${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${message}"
        createDirs="true"/>
</targets>

<rules>
   <logger name="CrmConnect" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="createPortalRegForm"/>
   <logger name="loggerCreatePortal" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="createPortalRegForm"/> 
   <logger name="loggerCreateRegData" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="createPortalRegFormData"/>
</rules>
```

- `<logger name=` should match the `LogManager.GetLogger(name)`
- `<logger writeTo=` should match the `<target name="`

See also: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial , and how `<logger name`-filter is working: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#logger-name-filter